# Pellet doesn't include my SWRL rules

Tags: jena, pellet, swrl

I build an ontology which uses SWRL rules to inference. When I do a SQWRL querying in Protege it works fine. The problem is, when i want to use Pellet with Jena, it seems like Pellet doesn't include the SWRL rules in the querying. I include Pellet like this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Fakultet\\WeatherHealthcast1.owl"));
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.read(in, null);
OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC, model);

// Create a new query
String queryString =
            "PREFIX WeatherHealthcast: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2011/2/WeatherHealthcast.owl#> " +
            "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> " +
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
            "SELECT ?disease " +
            "WHERE { " +
            "      ?person rdf:type WeatherHealthcast:Person." +
            "      ?person foaf:firstName ?fn." +
            "      ?person foaf:lastName ?ln." +
            "      FILTER regex(str(?fn), \"Viktor\")." +
            "      FILTER regex(str(?ln), \"Taneski\")." +
            "      ?disease rdf:type WeatherHealthcast:Disease. " +
            "      ?person WeatherHealthcast:suffersFrom ?disease." +
            "}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

// Execute the query and obtain results
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, ontology);
ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();
System.out.println("TEST");

while (resultSet.hasNext())
{
    QuerySolution result = resultSet.next();
    RDFNode disease = result.get("disease");
    Resource resource = disease.asResource();

    System.out.println(" { Suffers from: " + resource.getLocalName() + " . }");
}
```

I also tried this:

```
Reasoner r = PelletReasonerFactory.theInstance().create();
InfModel inferenceModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(r, model);
```

but no progress. Any ideas? I need this for my diploma thesis. Thanks

Comment: Hello viktor, did you finally address your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, pellet cannot support SQWRL.  On the other hand, it supports SWRL but with some restrictions (see http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/faq/rules).

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but I think you should switch to owl full in order to get all your rules included in the reasoning.